# What is the best Jquery Carousel plugin to apply to a list of posts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, infinite-carousel

Summary:

> I want to create a shuffle functionality. To accomplish that:
>
> 1) Creating a random list of total available posts based on their
>   "ID";
>
> 2) Getting the full post data based on ID (at this point I have a
>   random array of posts)
>
> 3) Apply carousel that navigates through those random posts (still to
>   do and purpose of this question).

What would be the best carousel for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by far is flexslider.

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

and a live demo :

http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html

Answer (score 0):

I attached a link you can select which type of carousel you want here is so many carousel and best link for carousels:

[Best Carousels Examples](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)