# Displaying PDFs

Tags: javascript, ms-access, pdf, coldfusion

Currently I have code that displays PNG images and comments from a database linked to each Image. I realized that I will also need to do this for PDF files.

How would I edit the current code to display PDF documents instead of PNG Images?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>



        <cfquery datasource="AccessTest" name="qTest">
            SELECT P.Account, P.Image, P.Image_ID, C.Remarks, C.Users, C.Accounts, C.Date_Time
            FROM PictureDB AS P
            INNER JOIN CommentsDB AS C
            ON C.Image_ID = P.Image_ID
            ORDER BY P.Image_ID
        </cfquery>



    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js">
    </script>



    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var images = {
            <cfoutput query="qTest" group="Image_ID">
                "#qTest.Image_ID#": {
                    "image": "#qTest.Image#",
                    "remarks": [
                    <cfoutput>
                        "#qTest.Users#, #qTest.Date_Time# <br> #qTest.Remarks# <br> </br>",
                    </cfoutput>
                    ]
                },
            </cfoutput>
        };
          $("button").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var src = images[id].image;
            var desc = images[id].remarks.toString();

            $("#theImage").attr("src", src).removeClass("hide");
            $("#theDescription").html(desc).removeClass("hide");
            });
        });
    </script>


    </head>

    <body>


    <cfoutput query="qTest" group="Account">
        <button data-id="#qTest.Image_ID#">
            <table width="230">#qTest.Account# </table>
        </button>
    </cfoutput>

    <img id="theImage" class="hide">
    <div id="theDescription" class="hide">
    </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I suggest an anchor tag to the pdf file you wish to display.

Comment: It's technically possible via a number of methods (object tag, embed tag,  various javascript libraries) but it is generally advised against in general. As Dan suggested, usually the best route is to provide a link.

Comment: .. and even if you did embed the pdf's, you cannot *force* the browser to display them within the page. Depending on the browser settings, the user may be promoted to open/save the file instead, which would make for a poor user experience. So do not assume that you can display them within the html page, just like an image.

Comment: In that case is there a way to display them in a box similiar to an iframe. While still keeping the comments?

Comment: The question is not whether it *can* be done, but whether it can be done *consistently*. Pretty much all browsers support `<img>` (except maybe lynx). But they do not all support displaying pdf's inline. Not out of the box. They must be configured to do so. Most browser are, but .. not all. So you can only suggest the browser open the file inline. You cannot *force* it. You should do a search on displaying pdf's inline first. Read up on the options and pros/cons. (It is a very common question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that there is no straightforward way to display pdfs inline in a similar manner to images, you could consider the following:

- Use `cfpdf action = "thumbnail"` to [convert the pdf to a series of images](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfpdf).
- Then, load the images for a given pdf in a [jquery carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405322/what-is-the-best-jquery-carousel-plugin-to-apply-to-a-list-of-posts) to make them available to review.

Using a carousel to contain and display the pages of the 'pdf' would give you a result similar to when you display a single image for review and would probably let you retain a similar look and feel to your page.