# show pdf title information from a query?

Tags: html, coldfusion, title

I have a query that get details from a acount,and then I display that information on the

```
    <title>Attachments for <cfoutput>#GetDetails.TrackingNum# - #ucase(trim(GetDetails.Lname))#/#ucase(trim(GetDetails.Fname))# #GetDetails.JobTitle# at #GetDetails.EmployerName#</cfoutput></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css" media="all">
```

I display the image or the pdf

```
<cfoutput>

    <cfif find("image",#GetAttachment.ContentType# )>
        <cfimage action="writeToBrowser" source="#GetAttachment.FileData#" width="1000" >

    <cfelse> 
        <cfcontent type="#GetAttachment.ContentType#" variable="#GetAttachment.FileData#" >     

    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

The image title does display but when I pull a PDF it does not display the title information , which it is on the query.

Why does the PDF does not display the title? What the PDF actually shows is the url.

I also notice it shows differently in different browsers IE, FIREFOX, CHROME.
Im trying to get it to work on IE 8.

Comment: You don't need the `# #` around variables the way you're using it in your `<cfif>` statement. e.g. `<cfif find("image",#GetAttachment.ContentType# )>` can be written just as `<cfif find("image", GetAttachment.ContentType)>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `cfcontent` to output the PDF any existing generated content is discarded - only the PDF is sent to the browser.

The docs for [`cfcontent`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfcontent) state "... when using the `file` attribute ... any other output on the current CFML page is ignored; only the contents of the file are sent to the client."

You may like to consider my answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005480/displaying-pdfs/21011999#21011999) for an approach to simulate embedding the PDF in a page.